# Eclipse custom builder: Identifying and cleaning generated files

Tags: java, build, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am creating a plugin for Eclipse, which contains tools for creating a custom type of project. These projects have a custom nature and builder. My builder (implements IncrementalProjectBuilder) takes a single input file, and generates a few (usually between 3 and 5) output files. When I run Clean Project, I need to remove the files the builder has previously generated.

Problem 1: The names of the generated files are not known exactly, but I do know the sort of files I expect to find (e.g. I know the extensions, and partial file names).

Problem 2: The user may add their own files to the project, which should not be affected by my build / clean steps.

My initial attempt was naive: remove every file except from the input file. This works, but has obvious problems.

My second attempt was better: I came up with a list of possible file names that may be generated, see if any of them exist and remove them.

- By only knowing partial file names and matching them, I may inadvertently delete a user's file. E.g. I know I will generate a file called *_file.py. If the file I generate is called abc_file.py and the user has added their own xyz_file.py, I want to clean (remove) abc_file.py but leave xyz_file.py untouched.
- The program which generates the output files from the input is constantly changing, and I don't want to rely on a concrete list of files that would need constant maintenance.

So, my question comes down to this. What methods exist for identifying the files generated by my custom builder, so I can remove them during a clean?

I've spent a couple of days Googling this one with not much to show for it. I am vaguely aware of a file system watcher in Java (Java7 WatchService?), but I don't know if that's the best solution to this problem.

Any information, advice or ideas appreciated.

Comment: Is your builder using the `IFile` API to create the files?

Comment: No. My builder passes the input file to another program, which generates the output files in the same directory. This other program has no dependencies on Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One brute force approach would be to compare the project before and after the other program is invoked to get the list of files that were created/generated.  Of course, it would be ideal if that program could somehow tell you which files it created.  Once you have that list, you could iterate over those files as IFile's as use the setDerived() method to mark them as not being source files.  When it comes time to clean the directory, you could use the derived setting to decide which files can be deleted.

Comment: This sounds like a sensible route to take. I work on the program that generates the files too, so I could get a list of created files from it if necessary (with a bit of refactoring) but I'd rather not go that route if I can avoid it. Thanks for pointing me at setDerived(), that sure looks useful. +1 (if I had the rep).

Comment: By comparing the project before / after the build, I got the list of files I needed. Marking them as derived made the cleaning step very easy. You were right on the money here, thanks!